# Is it possible to find the class of Controller which will handle the request from its path in Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httphandler

We have implemented an api service.

We are using attribute routes in our controllers (`config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`).

I am trying to write a handler which is required to work for some specific class of controllers.

Is it possible to get the actual controller class which will process the request in

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //...
}
```

of `DelegatingHandler`?

At the moment I can filter them using their path.

Comment: Are you sure you need to implement a `DelegatingHandler`? Your description clearly points towards an `ActionFilter` instead. Inside the action filter you have complete access to the request, controller and action called.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma This handler checks request whether they are valid or not. If they are not valid a fix error response is returned directly from handler without initialising the controllers. If I use ActionFilter, as far as I know Controllers are also initialised. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes they are, but from what I can see you *need* to know which controller is selected. As you can see from [this document](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf), the controller type is selected only after any `DelegatingHandler` execution and before any `Filter` (inside `HttpControllerDispatcher` precisely). I do not believe there is any other hook-point for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen inside [ASP.NET Web API 2: HTTP message lifecycle](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) document, the controller type selection and creation is done *after* the execution of any `DelegatingHandler` in the pipeline but before any `AuthenticationFilter`, `AuthorizationFilter` or `ActionFilter`.

So if you need to know which controller will handle the request, your best option is to implement your logic inside an `ActionFilter` (or possibly an `AuthorizationFilter` so you may skip `ModelBinding` entirely if the request is not valid).

Here you may access to the controller data using `ControllerContext` property of `HttpActionContext` parameter.